# Не могу получить из данного метода array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "1111",
database: "crypto"
});
function get_date() {
con.connect(function () {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM btc", function (err, result, fields) {
    var array = [];
    var string = JSON.stringify(result);
    var json = JSON.parse(string);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (json[i].price != "null") {
            array.push(json[i].price)
        }
    }
    return array
   })
});
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Зачем вы второй раз задаёте тот же вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDate() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        con.connect(() => {
            con.query(`SELECT * FROM btc`, (error, result, fields) => {
                const array = [];
                const string = JSON.stringify(result);
                const json = JSON.parse(string);
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if (json[i].price != 'null') {
                        array.push(json[i].price);
                    }
                }
                resolve(array);
            });
        });
    });
}

// 1)
(async () => {
    const array = await getDate();
})();

// 2)
getDate().then((array) => {
    const first = array[0];
});
```

Comment: Извините, а как бы мне вывести array в отдельную переменную чтобы потом передавать как аргумент, а то с concole.log() у меня все работало